# Parallelize Copy task in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I've got the following task in Gradle 4 build:

```
task copyWsdlFromArtifacts(type: Copy) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    from((configurations.wsdlAndXsdSourcesCompile.files + configurations.wsdlAndXsdSources.files).collect { zipTree(it)})
    into "$buildDir/schema/"
    include '**/*.xsd', '**/*.wsdl'
}
```

This is now a bottleneck. Is there a way to parallelize it somehow? Thank you very much!

Comment: There's an issue [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2678) to make the [FileOperations](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/FileOperations.java) available to parallel workers. Once this is resolved you  [use the worker api](https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is doing quite a lot of "work" in the configuration phase with all that unzipping and calculating file hashes for each of the unzipped files. You could improve performance by using the zips as task inputs which will mean unzipping is only done when the task is not `UP-TO-DATE`

Eg:

```
task copyWsdlFromArtifacts {
    inputs.files configurations.wsdlAndXsdSourcesCompile
    inputs.files configurations.wsdlAndXsdSources
    outputs.dir "$buildDir/schema/"

    doLast {
        copy {
            includeEmptyDirs = false
            from((configurations.wsdlAndXsdSourcesCompile.files + configurations.wsdlAndXsdSources.files).collect { zipTree(it)})
            into "$buildDir/schema/"
            include '**/*.xsd', '**/*.wsdl'            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing is that I wanted to paralellize unpacking execution. so I've created several tasks so that Gradle could execute them in parallel

Comment: your parallel solution still does the unpacking in the configuration phase on the main thread. `Copy.from(...)` is calculated in the configuration phase so the unzipping is happening then when it could be skipped with my solution

Comment: seems like neither approach works: gradle doesn't execute tasks within one module in parallel

Comment: you could split my `doLast { ... }` block into multiple `Runnable` and run them on a thread pool. Probably frowned upon in the gradle world but as long as you clean up the thread pool in a finally block it will be ok

Comment: got it, it is worth trying. maybe you also have an idea of how to run list of tasks in parallel? I've found [a plugin](https://github.com/barryearles/parallel-tasks-gradle-plugin) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Ultimately you should be using the [worker api](https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/) but you can't until [FileOperations](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/FileOperations.java) is available to workers. Perhaps you could contribute a patch for [this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2678)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a task per each artifact and running the whole build in parallel:

```
(configurations.wsdlAndXsdSourcesCompile.files + configurations.wsdlAndXsdSources.files).each { artifact ->
    tasks.create(name: "copyWsdlFromArtifacts$artifact", type: Copy) {
        from zipTree(artifact)
        into "$buildDir/schema/"
        include '**/*.xsd', '**/*.wsdl'
    }

    wsdl2java.dependsOn(tasks.findByName("copyWsdlFromArtifacts$artifact"))
}
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: This solution does NOT do the unzipping in parallel. The `zipTree(...)` is executed in the configuration phase, on the main thread and in series, not parallel.